# nservicebus configuration in .config file - how to enter?

Tags: configuration, nservicebus

nservicebus configuration in .config file - how to enter, do I have to typ[e all that manually if i want the config to come from the config file or there is an automated option to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Message routing can be done either via configuration file or [via code](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/routing).

Routing can be [extended](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/routing-extensibility) to support scenarios where routing information is either comming from a single source such as data source or routes need to be calculated at runtime.